# Can't install aws-cli via CF

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I can't install aws-cli via CF. I tried the set of codes via CLI and it works. But for some reason, it doesn't run as expected. When I run "aws --version" via ssh on the EC2, it generates: `"-bash: aws: command not found".`

----- Code:
NatInstanceAZA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance  **** text in between

---

```
  UserData:
    !Base64
      Fn::Sub: |
        #!/bin/sh
        echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
        echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/send_redirects
        /sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 0.0.0.0/0 -j MASQUERADE
        /sbin/iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables
        mkdir -p /etc/sysctl.d/
        cat <<EOF > /etc/sysctl.d/nat.conf
        net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
        net.ipv4.conf.eth0.send_redirects = 0
        sudo yum -y install aws-cli #supposed to install aws-cli
        EOF
```

Comment: the AMI I'm currently using is ami-ba7538e8

Comment: in ap-southeast-1

Answer (score 1):

UserData is executed as root so there is no need to use `sudo` when performing the `yum -y install aws-cli` command. When you SSH into the instance it is likely you are connecting as `ec2-user`, try switching to root with `sudo su -` and run `aws --version` again.

Check out this similar question and its accepted answer: [Calling AWS cli from user-data file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34497265/calling-aws-cli-from-user-data-file).

Alternatively you could look at installing AWS cli using Python and Pip which has a `--user` flag specifying the user it should be installed for.